# In a pandas DataFrame, how can "flattened" variables be "unflattened" into new columns using their index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flatten

I have some data in pandas DataFrames that was accessing using [root_pandas](https://github.com/scikit-hep/root_pandas) from a [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) file. Most of the data are simple variables that can have various values. Some variables, however, are arrays of numbers. In order to load these arrays, there is the option of *flattening* the variable.

So, for instance, the array variable `jet_tagWeightBin` can have various numbers of values depending on the number of jets in a physics event. When "flattened", one can access its various values for each jet in a given physics event by using an index, `__array_index`.

Here is what it looks like to load *three* physics events. You can see that for each physics event there is one value of `HT_jets` but multiple values of `jet_tagWeightBin` which are accessible using their index:

```
|  |HT_jets|jet_tagWeightBin|__array_index|
|--|-------|----------------|-------------|
|0 |319676 |1               |0            |     |<---------- 1st event
|1 |319676 |5               |1            |     |
|2 |319676 |1               |2            |     |
|3 |319676 |5               |3            |     |
|4 |200476 |5               |0            |        |<------- 2nd event
|5 |200476 |2               |1            |        |
|6 |200476 |1               |2            |        |
|7 |200476 |1               |3            |        |
|8 |520111 |5               |0            |           |<---- 3rd event
|9 |520111 |1               |1            |           |
|10|520111 |2               |2            |           |
|11|520111 |5               |3            |           |
|12|520111 |5               |4            |           |
|13|520111 |2               |5            |           |
```

Here's that in code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             [319676, 1, 0],
             [319676, 5, 1],
             [319676, 1, 2],
             [319676, 5, 3],
             [200476, 5, 0],
             [200476, 2, 1],
             [200476, 1, 2],
             [200476, 1, 3],
             [520111, 5, 0],
             [520111, 1, 1],
             [520111, 2, 2],
             [520111, 5, 3],
             [520111, 5, 4],
             [520111, 2, 5],
         ],
         columns = [
             "HT_jets",
             "jet_tagWeightBin",
             "__array_index"
         ]
    )
```

Now, what I want to do is get rid of that `__array_index` and by adding a bunch of new single-value variables like `jet_tagWeightBin_0`, `jet_tagWeightBin_1`, `jet_tagWeightBin_2`, ..., up to as many as are needed. So, I want to get to something like this:

```
|  |HT_jets|jet_tagWeightBin_0|jet_tagWeightBin_1|jet_tagWeightBin_2|jet_tagWeightBin_3|jet_tagWeightBin_4|jet_tagWeightBin_5|
|--|-------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|0 |319676 |1                 |5                 |1                 |5                 |NaN               |NaN               |
|1 |200476 |5                 |2                 |1                 |1                 |NaN               |NaN               |
|2 |520111 |5                 |1                 |2                 |5                 |5                 |2                 |
```

I'm not sure what this type of operation is, but I feel sure that this must be some straightforward thing to do. I just don't know how to do it.

Anyway, here's the beginnings of an attempt:

I can add a new column with the appropriate name like this:

```
df["new_name"] = df.apply(lambda row: "jet_tagWeightBin_" + str(row["__array_index"]), axis = 1)
```

That results in this:

```
|  |HT_jets|jet_tagWeightBin|__array_index|new_name          |
|--|-------|----------------|-------------|------------------|
|0 |319676 |1               |0            |jet_tagWeightBin_0|
|1 |319676 |5               |1            |jet_tagWeightBin_1|
|2 |319676 |1               |2            |jet_tagWeightBin_2|
|3 |319676 |5               |3            |jet_tagWeightBin_3|
|4 |200476 |5               |0            |jet_tagWeightBin_0|
|5 |200476 |2               |1            |jet_tagWeightBin_1|
|6 |200476 |1               |2            |jet_tagWeightBin_2|
|7 |200476 |1               |3            |jet_tagWeightBin_3|
|8 |520111 |5               |0            |jet_tagWeightBin_0|
|9 |520111 |1               |1            |jet_tagWeightBin_1|
|10|520111 |2               |2            |jet_tagWeightBin_2|
|11|520111 |5               |3            |jet_tagWeightBin_3|
|12|520111 |5               |4            |jet_tagWeightBin_4|
|13|520111 |2               |5            |jet_tagWeightBin_5|
```

That's where I'm at. I'd welcome guidance. :)

---

EDIT: For clarity, I'm dealing with many variables. Here are more columns in the data:

```
|  |eventNumber|Mjj_MindR   |HT_jets|jet_tagWeightBin|__array_index|
|--|-----------|------------|-------|----------------|-------------|
|0 |446427     |98896.421875|319676 |1               |0            |     |<---------- 1st event
|1 |446427     |98896.421875|319676 |5               |1            |     |
|2 |446427     |98896.421875|319676 |1               |2            |     |
|3 |446427     |98896.421875|319676 |5               |3            |     |
|4 |446650     |29691.271484|200476 |5               |0            |        |<------- 2nd event
|5 |446650     |29691.271484|200476 |2               |1            |        |
|6 |446650     |29691.271484|200476 |1               |2            |        |
|7 |446650     |29691.271484|200476 |1               |3            |        |
|8 |446707     |57697.246094|520111 |5               |0            |          |<---- 3rd event
|9 |446707     |57697.246094|520111 |1               |1            |          |
|10|446707     |57697.246094|520111 |2               |2            |          |
|11|446707     |57697.246094|520111 |5               |3            |          |
|12|446707     |57697.246094|520111 |5               |4            |          |
|13|446707     |57697.246094|520111 |2               |5            |          |
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot problem

```
newDF = df.pivot(columns='array_index', values='jet_tagWeightBin', index='HT_jets')
```

Then just rename the columns

This gives:

```
array_index    0    1    2    3    4    5
HT_jets
200476       5.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
319676       1.0  5.0  1.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
520111       5.0  1.0  2.0  5.0  5.0  2.0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, this seems to come close to what I need. So, as mentioned, I have a whole bunch of variables that have a single value per event, not just `HT_jets` (which itself cannot be assumed to be a number unique to each event -- I have the variable `eventNumber` which can be used for this). When I do as you suggest, it nukes all of my other columns of variables. How should I proceed? Should I have a separate DataFrame for array variables and then try to merge it with a DataFrame for single-value variables?

Comment: I've added a few more columns at the end of my post to illustrate.